Creating custom Fields in MSWord - Determining where a VBA to C# conversion is going wrong
I've been converting VBA to other languages for years, this is the first time I've been completely stumped. In this case, it's a Word VBA project being converted to a C# VSTO application.
Let me start with the original VBA code:
    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
    Selection.TypeText Text:="TC """
    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
    Selection.TypeText Text:="IF "
...

It goes on, but the failure in my conversion will happen by that second line.
I rewrote each two-line set (Field Add and TypeText) as a method:
...
                Application curApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
...
                AddField(curApp.Selection, @" TC """);
                AddField(curApp.Selection, @" IF ");
...

    private void AddField(Selection selection, string typeText)
    {
        try
        {
            selection.Fields.Add(selection.Range, WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, false);
            selection.TypeText(typeText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
        }
    }

In frustration, I also wrote it more verbatim:
        curApp.Selection.Fields.Add(curApp.Selection.Range, WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, false);
        curApp.Selection.TypeText(@" TC """);
        curApp.Selection.Fields.Add(curApp.Selection.Range, WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, false);
        curApp.Selection.TypeText(@" IF ");

Running VBA, I get what I'm expecting (in the Word document):
{ TC "{ IF  }}

In both the C# cases, I get:
{ 0 \ MERGEFORMAT } TC "{ 0 \ MERGEFORMAT } IF

I'm trying to determine why C# (VSTO) is being interpreted so differently than what seems like largely the same code as VBA for this case. I know it's something silly I'm doing on my part, but I just can't see it.

Fields.Add takes 4 arguments, but your C# code only uses 3. Your are missing argument 3 - Text.

Well, that is a simple answer! Feel bad I missed that during the conversion. Worked perfectly. Thank you!
